# Why are my SMS messages sent via Amazon SNS not being received by Indian phone numbers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send text SMS using Amazon SNS in my Springboot application.

This is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("aws")
public class AwsConfig {

    private String accessKeyId;
    private String secretAccessKey;

    public String getAccessKeyId() {
        return accessKeyId;
    }

    public void setAccessKeyId(String accessKeyId) {
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
    }

    public String getSecretAccessKey() {
        return secretAccessKey;
    }

    public void setSecretAccessKey(String secretAccessKey) {
        this.secretAccessKey = secretAccessKey;
    }

    public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsCredentials() {
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey );
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService getAmazonSimpleEmailService() {
        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awsCredentials())
                .withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AmazonSNS getAmazonSNS() {
        return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awsCredentials())
                .withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    }
}
```

This is the class to send messages:

```
@Service
public class SmsSendingServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonSNS amazonSNS;
    
    public void sendSMS()
    {
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
         smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue()
                    .withStringValue("SENDER") 
                    .withDataType("String"));
         smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", new MessageAttributeValue()
                    .withStringValue("Transactional")
                    .withDataType("String"));
         
         try {
                PublishResult result = amazonSNS.publish(new PublishRequest()
                        .withMessage("This is a test sms.")
                        .withPhoneNumber("+91-**********").withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
                
                System.out.println("Messsage Sent. "+result.getMessageId());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
             
    }
}
```

On calling `sendSMS()` I do get the `Message Sent.` message in the console output, but no SMS is being received on the phone number mentioned.

I have tried several different phone numbers for this. None of them are receiving any messages.

It might be worth mentioning that all these numbers are Indian.

Can someone please point out what might be the cause for this?

This is the [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/UkZFXxwsE-M) I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue you are facing is that India is a country that has special requirements for using a non-numeric sender ID for SMS messages.**

---

Based on [Supported Regions and countries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html) documentation for SNS:

```
Country or region       ISO code        Supports sender IDs     Supports two-way SMS (Amazon Pinpoint only)
India                   IN              Yes3                    Yes
```

Note that the **Supports sender IDs** column for India is marked as **Yes<sup>3</sup>**.

Notes section states:

> 3. **Senders are required to use a pre-registered alphabetic sender ID. Additional registration steps are required.**  For more information, see Special requirements for sending SMS messages to recipients in India.

---

For your [origination identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities.html), you can either have [origination numbers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-origination-numbers.html) or [sender IDs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-sender-ids.html).

In your case, you cannot opt to use origination numbers as **Indian laws require the use of sender IDs instead**.

The opposite situation also exists as countries like Canada, China, and the United States require the use of *origination numbers* (read: [U.S. product number comparison](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-origination-numbers.html#sns-10dlc-product-comparison) for different number types for the number you need to purchase & the [SMS cost calculator](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/pricing/)).

From [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-sns-now-supports-selecting-the-origination-number-when-sending-sms-messages/):

> This feature (origination numbers) does not apply when sending SMS to countries where **local limitations, laws, or regulations require the use of Sender Ids in the place of origination numbers, for example India**.

Therefore, you must follow the [Special requirements for sending SMS messages to recipients in India](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html) guide. This is what is meant by *Additional registration steps are required* above.

---

**Unfortunately, there is no workaround for local country laws that AWS apparently needs to abide by.**

That said, there *may* be domestic services that can "circumvent" AWS's legal restriction (as they are domestic/may have special contracts with telecoms etc.). If you don't want to/can't register a sender ID, other services may also be worth looking at.

Comment: I tried - 1. removing the whole part that sets `SenderId`. 2. replacing `"SENDER"` with `"999"`. Still didn't receive the messages.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried using `.withDataType("Number")` , that isn't working either.

Comment: Yes, only the `;` positioned after `withStringValue("1234") )`.

Comment: @jennyjenkins Updated answer - apologies, you can't use origination numbers - you must register your sender IDs under Indian law, guide is linked

Comment: No unfortunately in your case. I have added an extra reference to the question - **where local limitations, laws, or regulations require the use of Sender Ids in the place of origination numbers, for example India.** - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-sns-now-supports-selecting-the-origination-number-when-sending-sms-messages/

Comment: Thank you! From what I was understanding , Sender Id is required if we don't want a random numeric Id appearing as the sender. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html

Comment: Ah nope, that's not the case - multiple sources point to the requirement of having a sender ID; I also assume you don't get transactional messages from businesses via phone numbers in India? If you do, there may be domestic services which can circumvent AWS's legal restriction (as they are domestic/may have special contracts with telecoms etc.) so other services may also be worth looking at if you do not want to register a sender ID. You're welcome!

Comment: Also, what do I need to send messages to US mobile numbers? Will I still need a registered _Origination number_?

Comment: You need a number but you don't need to register, you need to purchase - you can have 10 digit numbers, toll free numbers or short codes but as you're doing transcational, I would go for a [toll free number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-tfn.html) as it's [immediately provisioned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-origination-numbers.html) and requires no vetting. You purchase them within the [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the Sender ID, via DLT registration providers, also you have to register the templates there and get them approved.
There are many DLT registration providers.