# AWS SNS programmatically sending SMS is not delivered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-go

We want our cloud application on AWS to send SMS messages to Indian phones. We were able to send messages in AWS Pinpoint Sandbox. We registered with TRAI and got our SenderID, PEID, TemplateID, message format, etc. Now, when I publish message using AWS sdk, it gives me no error. It gives me a message ID too. However, message is not delivered. Cloudwatch does not show any logs.

```golang
//Here is how session is created
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
  Region:      aws.String("ap-south-1"),
  Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(myAWSID, myawssecretkey, mySession), //mySession is normally empty
})
```

That goes through with no error.

```golang
  //Create a new sns client from the session above
  snsSvc = sns.New(sess)
  //setting message parameters based on AWS documentation,
  params := &sns.PublishInput{
  Message:     aws.String(message),
  PhoneNumber: aws.String(PhoneNumber),
  MessageAttributes: map[string]*sns.MessageAttributeValue{

    "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID":  &sns.MessageAttributeValue{StringValue: aws.String(senderId), DataType: aws.String("String")},
    "AWS.MM.SMS.TemplateId": &sns.MessageAttributeValue{StringValue: aws.String(templateId), DataType: aws.String("String")},
    "AWS.MM.SMS.EntityId":   &sns.MessageAttributeValue{StringValue: aws.String(peid), DataType: aws.String("String")},

    "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": &sns.MessageAttributeValue{StringValue: aws.String("Transactional"), DataType: aws.String("String")},
  },
}

resp, err := snsSvc.Publish(params)
```

There is no error. I get a response from AWS as:

```
{  MessageId: "b781e287-4837-59b8-9edb-b90b05c3423b"}","time":"2022-09-02T18:30:12Z"}
```

Cloudwatch logs are always empty. Am I missing anything else above?

Comment: Is this by any chance related? I can't see your sender ID value here so not sure if it is or not: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69539036/4800344

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary, Thanks!. The senderID I am using is a 6 character sender ID as received from TRAI. There are no numerals in it. Updated my question

Comment: OK good to cancel that out - do you get that response from the API? Can you show us how you're making that call please?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I updated the question with actual code.